# Mac Automator - Service to resize/scale images using SIPS

Tags: mac, terminal, images, automator

I would like a service which scales selected images within Finder to X pixels (max length/width without upscaling if images are smaller than X). Image files can have all kinds of file extensions.

The idea:

1. Select image files in Finder
2. Right click and choose Services -> e.g. "Resize - 1920px"
3. The service receives the files and passes to SIPS, scaling the images to i.e. max 1920x1920 px.

Currently this is what I have in Automator, which doesn't work:

[Automator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87LMZ.png)

When run, I get the error message "The action "Run Shell Script" encountered an error":

[Run Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AAqs.png)

OS: Sierra 10.12.2

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a pretty useless statement by itself. I recommend [edit]ing your question and adding in details to explain how it's not working; error messages, incorrect results, etc...

Comment: You're completely right, question is now edited.

Comment: Ensure that your script runs via the command line and then try to place it within Automator.